# JavaFX Borderpane combined with Splitpane

Tags: java, javafx

I'm very new to JavaFX.
For a school project, I have to create a JavaFX application with three sectors (Left, Center, and bottom) which have to be resizable by dragging the divider line.

To create this layout I tried to use a BorderPane (for the sections) and combine it with a SplitPane to make it resizable. But I cannot figure out how to combine it.
Is this even possible or do I need another Pane-Object?

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane();
ScrollPane leftPane = new ScrollPane(new Button("Button 1"));
ScrollPane bottomPane = new ScrollPane(new Button("Button 2"));
FlowPane centerPane = new FlowPane(new Button("Button 3"));

//splitPane.getItems().addAll(leftPane, centerPane, bottomPane);
//root.getChildren().add(splitPane);
root.setLeft(leftPane);
root.setCenter(centerPane);
root.setBottom(bottomPane);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use two `SplitPanes` with different orientations (and forget about the `BorderPane`):

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SplitPanesExampleApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // Creating the controls:
        ScrollPane leftPane = new ScrollPane(new Button("Left")),
                bottomPane = new ScrollPane(new Button("Bottom"));

        FlowPane centerPane = new FlowPane(new Button("Center (or right)"));

        SplitPane horizontalSplitPane = new SplitPane(leftPane, centerPane),
                verticalSplitPane = new SplitPane(horizontalSplitPane, bottomPane);

        // Setting orientations:
        verticalSplitPane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        // horizontalSplitPane.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL); // horizontal is the default value

        // Setting initial divider positions:
        verticalSplitPane.getDividers().get(0).setPosition(.8);
        horizontalSplitPane.getDividers().get(0).setPosition(.2);

        // Prepare and show stage:
        stage.setScene(new Scene(verticalSplitPane, 600, 400));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW! thank you that's exactly I was looking for. Is it possible to set the width and  height of the elements to size it instead to set the divider position?

Comment: Nice. With `setPrefWidth` and `setPrefHeight` the values for the divider positions will keep their default value (0,5). They will change if you set e. g. a minimum width or height for the center pane, but this will limit the users capability of resizing. I think it is best to use dividers `setPosition` method.